# ACF Form Post not showing on frontend straight away

Tags: wordpress, forms, frontend, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF's front end editor capabilities to enable my users to upload a post to the site.

The user fills out the form and submits and the data shows correctly in the backend. The issue I'm facing is the homepage (which shows all the latest posts) has to be refreshed in order to show the post that has just been uploaded.

Is there a way this can populate straight away? The idea is once the user has filled out the front end form, they are taken to the post they have just created (which works fine). If they then click onto the homepage, they should be able to see the post title there without having to refresh the page.

My form code is:

```
<?php acf_form(array(
    'post_id' => 'new_post',

    'field_groups' => array(152),
    'new_post' => array (
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ),
    'post_title'    => true,
    'submit_value'  => 'Submit',
'return' => '%post_url%'
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by adding

```
 ?loggedin=true
```

to the end of the URL when the user logs in and gets redirected to their profile.